# Similarity function in ElasticSearch that is independent from the number of documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

I need a similarity function from elasticsearch that returns a score which is independent from the number of documents. All functions are dependent from the term-frequency. How can I solve this problem and make the score returned by elasticsearch deterministic?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: Take a look here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions